# Generic way to get the value of an input regardless of type

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I'm trying to write a generic function I can use with the jquery validation plugin that will make a field required based on the value of another field. Here's what I want to happen:

- If Field 1's value is in a specified array of values (currently testing with "No", "n/a", and "0"), or is empty, do nothing. Otherwise, make Field 2 required.

Getting the value of Field 1 is the issue. I had no problem figuring this out with a text-type or `<select>` input, but I'm trying to get it to work with radios and having difficulty. Here is an excerpt from my code:

```
var value = $('[name="option"]').val(),
    empty = ['no', '', 'n/a', '0'];

// If the input is not "empty", make the additional field required
if ($.inArray(value.toLowerCase(), empty) < 0) { // returns -1 if not found
    required = true;
} else {
    required = false;
}
```

This works for everything I need it to except radios, because it seems to read the value of the first radio, regardless of if it was checked or not.

The field that will trigger the "required" will either be one of the various text inputs (`text`, `url`, `email`, etc.), a `<select>`, or a single choice set of radios. No multiple choice. I'll be passing this function as a parameter to `required` in my jquery validation config for each field I want it to apply to. The `name` attribute of the "other" field that gets evaluated will be available to it.

Here's my demo so far, kind of ugly but there are notes: http://jsfiddle.net/uUdX2/3/

I've tried a bunch of different ways using `is(':checked')` and the `:checked` selector, but they have all failed. I removed them from the demo because they didn't work.

What do I need to get this working with radios *and* text-type or select inputs, without knowing which kind of input it will be?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
var value = $('[name="option"]');
var type = value.attr("type");

if(type && type.toLowerCase() == 'radio')
  value = value.filter(":checked").val();
else
  value = value.val();
```

Working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uUdX2/7/)

Comment: I'm not sure why I didn't think of this myself, this works perfectly. I believe this should work for multiple choice inputs as well if I need it to. Sometimes we just need another set of eyes after a long day. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
var value = $('[type="radio"][name="option"]:checked, [type!="radio"][name="option"]', form).val() || '0'
```

Quite similar to Shankar's but does it all in the selector.

http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/uUdX2/8/

It's not working when nothing is selected. Not sure what you want it to do when that happens?

Comment: I tried something similar and couldn't get it to work, but this seems like another good way to do it (I can probably figure out the little bug). I like this method because it uses one selector (sort of). EDIT: I left a note in the demo about what should happen if nothing is checked: "If "No" is checked or nothing is checked, additional field should not be required." Sorry to not clarify in my post.

Comment: I've fixed the little bug by adding the `|| '0'` at the end of the value line. This way if it doesn't find a value it defaults to 0 which then will display the message.

Comment: Works great, wish I could accept both answers. I'm using the other method for now, but I have no qualms with switching accepted answers if I end up using your method. Really appreciate it Richard. ShankarSangoli's method really made me facepalm though! (as in: Why didn't I think of this??)

Comment: Heh, I do it all the time. You were probably concentrating too much on not directly filtering radio buttons :D