# Check value of input field regardless of type

Tags: javascript

I've seen and read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059391/generic-way-to-get-the-value-of-an-input-regardless-of-type) question. Didn't quite find my answer there.

I have some code that accept an html template, and uses that template inside a form.
That template will contain x number of input fields.

Is there a way to check for a value in those input fields generically?
Kinda like this:

```
var inputFields = element.getElementsByTagName('input');
inputFields.forEach(function (element) {
    var value = element.value;
    // ... something
});
```

I know that won't work, but you get the idea.

I think I have to write special cases for different input types, but i thought I'd ask if anyone have any experience with this problem.

This is done in pure JavaScript, so I don't really need jQuery. Unless you have a really neat way to do it in jQyery, compared to just plain JavaScript.

EDIT: I need to check if any input has been entered into the field, whether it is a file or text. I need to remove the name attribute on those who have no value.

Comment: what do you mean by checking?

Comment: _"I think I have to write special cases for different input types"_ - Why do you think that? All `<input>` elements will have a value (though that value may be an empty string). When you say "check for a value" do you mean you have some known value, say "123", and you want to know if any inputs have the value "123"?

Comment: Use JQuery. Plenty of examples are available over the internet. It's a piece of cake :)

Comment: but you should know how to eat it @Abhinabyte :)

Comment: @nnnnnn Yes, I know they have the attribute. But, if it is a file upload, the value field will be empty. So that's why I'm asking.

Comment: @AmitJoki See my edit. Expanded a little bit.

Comment: How do radio buttons apply here? Do you mean if no radio button in a given group has been selected remove the name attribute? Because only checked radio buttons get submitted anyway...

Comment: You simply read the *value* property. You might want to only get the value of a checkbox or radio button if it's checked, and might want to ignore inputs like *submit*, *reset*, *button* but jQuery won't help you with that anyway.

Comment: "*I need to remove the name attribute on those who have no value*". Why? If you are trying to prevent the submission of fields with no value and expect them not to turn up at the server when the form is submitted, then javascript is a very unreliable tool for that.

Comment: @nnnnnn Sorry, radio buttons was a bad example.

Comment: @RobG Would you recommend to just handle it on the server?

Comment: @kjelelokk—yes, that would be very much more reliable.

Comment: @RobG I'm already dependent on the javascript assigning the right names to the name attributes, due to the dynamic nature of the module. That already works fine. Without javascript it wont work anyway.

Comment: @kjelelokk—it's not about whether javascript is available, but that the client can send whatever it likes to the server, you have no control. If you are dealing with that already (at the server), then removing names to prevent submission seems a bit pointless.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following, I can't see that you need any special handling for different types. You can just read the value property:

```
<script>
  var t = '<table>';
  var inputTypes = ('hidden text tel url email password datetime date month week' +
                    ' time number range color checkbox radio file submit image' +
                    ' reset button').split(' ');
  var type;

  for (var i=0, iLen=inputTypes.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    type = inputTypes[i];
    value = type == 'number'? 10 : 'input type ' + type;
    t += '<tr><td>' + type + '<td><input type="' + type +
         '" name="' + type + 'Input" value="' + value + '">';
  }
  document.write(t + '<\/table>');
</script>

<button onclick="getValues(document.getElementsByTagName('input'))">Get values</button>

<script>
function getValues(inputs) {
  var input;
  for (var i=0, iLen=inputs.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    input = inputs[i];
    console.log(input.name + ': ' + input.value);
  }
}
</script>
```

You may want to check that checkboxes and radios are checked. For that, getting the value can be:

```
if (input.type in {radio:'', checkbox:''}) {

  if (input.checked) {
    // get value
  }

} else {
  // get value
}
```